# Representation of the action of $ S_3 $ on $ (1,2,-3) \in M$ On the plane

Tags: permutations, group-actions, symmetry

Consider the action of the permutation group  $S_3$ on the vector space $M =\lbrace (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3,  \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0\rbrace$.

The problem I have is the following: represent the action of $S_3$ on $\lambda = (1,2,-3) \in M $ on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (wich we  identifiy with M).

The hints I've been given is first to choose an orthonormal basis of M and then to draw the two axis of symmetry wich represent the two generators of $S_3$ namely the permutations $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

My questions are:

1. why do we have to choose an orthonormal basis of M, is it not enought to work with an arbitrary basis ?
2. what are the equations of the two axis of symmetry in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that we use to illustrate the image of  $\lambda $ under the action of $S_3$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why do we have to choose an orthonormal basis of $M$, is it not enough to work with an arbitrary basis ?

I guess in general you don't have to choose an orthonormal basis. You could still choose *any* basis and identify $M$ with $\Bbb{R}^2$ in such a way. Maybe though, since all permutation matrices have determinant $\pm 1$, and are thus orthogonal, it is nice to choose an orthonormal basis so that they remain orthogonal transformations in the new basis.

> 2. what are the equations of the two axis of symmetry in $\Bbb{R}^2$ that we use to illustrate the image of $\lambda$ under the action of $S^3$?

This will depend on the basis you choose for $M$. In $\Bbb{R}^3$, the action of $(1,2)$ is the reflection over the plane $y=x$. This plane intersects $M$ in the line spanned by the vector $(1,1,-2)$. So the action of $(1,2)$ on $M$ is the reflection over this line. After choosing a basis, you can try to express this line in those coordinates.

Similarly, the permutation $(2,3)$ acts as reflection over the plane $y=z$, which intersects $M$ in the line spanned by $(-2,1,1)$. Again, you'll want to find an equation for this line in the coordinates corresponding to the basis you choose for $M$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Could you just explain the last sentence in your answer to the first question! My understanding to it was that if we choose an orthonormal basis of M, then it's image under the isomorphism of identification gives us an orthormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is this what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, that is partly what I meant. But also, permutation matrices have the property that $P^T P = \mathrm{Id}$ (they are orthogonal matrices). My point was that if you change basis to an orthonormal basis, then the new matrix $\widetilde{P}$ in the new basis will still have this property: $\widetilde{P} \widetilde{P}^T = \mathrm{Id}$.